# sqlserver assigning last inserted Id to another column in one query

Tags: sql-server

when this query is executed

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,Name VARCHAR(50),ID2 INT NULL)
INSERT INTO @Temp ([Name]) VALUES ('Ali')
UPDATE @Temp SET ID2= (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()) WHERE [ID]=(SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())
INSERT INTO @Temp ([Name]) VALUES ('Veli')
UPDATE @Temp SET ID2= (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()) WHERE [ID]=(SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())
SELECT * FROM @Temp
```

We can get this table

```
ID-NAME-ID2
1 - Ali - 1
2 - Veli - 2
```

is there a way to do this in one insert query ( Assigning inserted id to another column without using idendity property in that column) ?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make it a computed column like below

```
create TABLE Temp(ID INT IDENTITY,Name 
                  VARCHAR(50),
                  ID2 AS ID PERSISTED);
```

Then insert rows ... your ID values will be persisted in ID2 column

```
INSERT INTO Temp ([Name]) 
VALUES ('Ali');

INSERT INTO Temp ([Name]) 

VALUES ('Veli');

INSERT INTO Temp ([Name]) 

VALUES ('Neli');
```

Which will results in

[image]

See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59fca/1

**EDIT:**

If you can't change your table structure then the only way insert ID value to ID2 column is the way you are currently doing it cause in same insert statement the identity value is still not available and so it will be null.

Comment: Thanks but this is not my table (actual db)(not my application), so  i could not change table definition. i want to only insert data to db.

Comment: @ttn, don't forget to mark it as answer (by clicking the check button below voting button) if it helped.

Comment: thank you very much, so can we say we could not use select scope identity in insert query

Comment: @ttn, Yes that's exactly what I mean.